# Kusto join rows using an id and display the contents as an array

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is there a way to join multiple rows by a distinct id and show those rows as an array or a comma separated string?

e.g.

```
| id | value |
|  1 | A     |
|  1 | B     |
|  1 | C     |
```

into

```
| id | values |
|  1 | A,B,C  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [make_list()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction) operator to show them as an array, the syntax is as below:

```
your_table_name
| summarize mylist = make_list(value) by id
```

Here is an example:

[image]